# java sugaring, can I avoid almost-duplicate code here?

Tags: java, android, syntactic-sugar

```
private class HSV extends HorizontalScrollView {
    public LinearLayout L;
    public AbsoluteLayout A;
    public HSV(Context context) {
        super(context);
        L = new LinearLayout(context);
        A = new AbsoluteLayout(context);
    }
    @Override public void addView(View child) {
        A.addView(child);
    }
    void update_scroll() {
        removeView(L);
        addView(L, 0);
        L.removeView(A);
        L.addView(A);
        A.invalidate();
        L.invalidate();
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
    int GetCurrentPos() {
        return getScrollX(); // <-- this line if HSV
        return getScrollY(); // <-- this line if VSV
    }
    ... few more methods skipped, they will not change at all in 'vertical' version
}
```

I have this class, it perfectly does what I want. Now I need new class VSV which will derive from (vertical)ScrollView and be just the same. I surely can just copy whole block and change **extends HorizontalScrolView** to **extends ScrollView**, and then **(L, 0)** to **(0, L)** (oops, this was a mistake when publishing on SO, surely that line will not change, the GetCurrentPos will).

or I can add "bool vertical" property. But Java has no templates or macros, nor runtime prototyping, so is there any other way in Java to avoid code duplication in this example?

Comment: Have a common base class and derive a vertical class and a horizontal class. Either with constructor param orientation (à la swing) or overriding.

Comment: If you derive the VSV class from HSV. You can simply override the addView method with an empty method. Maybe you should extract it first to an other method and then override it.

Comment: I would stay with those two classes. You will make your code more complicated and harder to debug when trying to merge them. And the time thinking about this isn't worth the few trivial lines of code you are saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [android.widget.ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) and [android.widget.HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html), both of them seem to implement

```
void addView(View child, int index)
```

So you would not have to change that line of code, if I am not missing anything here. Also, both classes inherit this method from [android.view.ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html). So, if the implementation of both classes is the same, you could do something like this

```
public abstract class ScrollViewDelegate<T extends FrameLayout> {
  private final T view;
  private LinearLayout L;
  private AbsoluteLayout A;

  public ScrollViewWrapper(T view) {
    this.view = view;
    L = new LinearLayout(view.getContext());   // or pass as parameter
    A = new AbsoluteLayout(view.getContext()); // or pass as parameter
  }

  void update_scroll() {
      view.removeView(L);
      view.addView(L, 0);
      L.removeView(A);
      L.addView(A);
      A.invalidate();
      L.invalidate();
      view.invalidate();
      view.requestLayout();
  }
  // ...
}
```

and in HSV/VSV you can delegate to this class (if necessary).

```
public class HSV extends HorizontalScrollView {

  private final ScrollViewDelegate<HorizontalScrollView> delegate;

  public HSV(Context context) {
      super(context);
      this.delegate = new ScrollViewDelegate<HorizontalScrollView>(this);
  }
  // do stuff with this.delegate
}

public class VSV extends ScrollView {

  private final ScrollViewDelegate<ScrollView> delegate;

  public VSV(Context context) {
      super(context);
      this.delegate = new ScrollViewDelegate<ScrollView>(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: But what is that <T extends FrameLayout> thing? It looks like C++ template, I mean those <> and T. But how about "Java has no template support"?

Comment: Java has had generic classes for several versions now, which are similar to C++'s templates in that a `LinkedList<>` can be a `LinkedList<String>` or a `LinkedList<Object>`, just like C++'s templated collections

Comment: Java generics have existed for almost 10 years.

Comment: For a while I stick to having duplicate code, but my thanks any way, later if I find time will try your solution. But I will need to understand what is "delegate" first. Right now will use: if (findViewById(ID) instanceof HSV)...