# Java 'T extends' 'hello-world' won't compile

Tags: java, generics

```
class root { public void say() { System.out.print("hello\n"); }}
class A extends root { @Override public void say() { System.out.print("world A\n"); }}
class B extends root { @Override public void say() { System.out.print("world B\n"); }}
//abstract class C extends <T> { public void go() { say(); say(); }}
class C <T extends root> { public void go() { say(); say(); }}

public class Template { public static void main(String[] args) {
    C c = new C<A>(); c.say();
    D d = new C<B>(); d.say();
}}
```

I need class C that will extend both A and B. (In real life they will be horizontal(A) and vertical(B) scroll view). But this will not compile. I browsed through dozens of examples you can find on the web and SO, but neither example is compilable program and they only confuse me more and more. Please help!

Comment: I realized that this is hard to explain what I want to achieve here. But here is my original question where user moxn suggested to use generics like that. But I am getting it wrong (or not getting it) obviously. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222285/java-sugaring-can-i-avoid-almost-duplicate-code-here

Comment: Before going any further with this project, I highly recommend you read through the [Oracle Tutorial on Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). It's a quick read and a decent starting point for you to understand how generics work and how you would use them in your code.

Comment: Also, Java (unlike C++) does not support multiple parents for a class. You get have 1 and only 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C` class doesn't have a `say` method, so the code will never compile. Also, it looks like there's no `D` class.

In order to make it compile, `C` should extend `root` or `C` should have a `say` method.

Lines of code with problems:

```
class C <T extends root> { public void go() { say(); say(); }}

C c = new C<A>(); c.say();
```

You can modify your code to this in order to make it run:

```
class C <T extends root> {

    T element;

    public C(T element) { this.element = element; }

    public go() { element.say(); }
}

//...

C c = new C<A>(new A()); c.go();
```

As stated in [Perception's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238418/java-t-extends-hello-world-wont-compile#comment21485920_15238418), you should check the [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) tutorial provided by Oracle to get better understanding on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `class C<T extends root>` it does **NOT** mean that `C` extends `root`.

It means that `C` is a class with a type parameter, `T`, which extends `root`.

This means a `C` object can accept as a type parameter any class that extends `root`.

Whether or not `C` extends `root` itself is completely unrelated.

To make `C` extend `root`, you simply use this: `class C extends root`

In your example, the purpose of the type parameter is not clear (ie you never use T).